# Unable to create object in event handler

Tags: 2011, event-system

I'm trying to deserialize application data and cast it to a specific type from within my event handler, but this seems impossible as it refuses to find my class even though it's compiled into the same assembly as the event handler.

Regardless if I use the ApplicationData utility `GetAs<T>()` or deserialize it myself I get the same error:

```
Could not cast as MyClass, reason: Unable to find assembly 'MyAssembly.MyClass, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryAssemblyInfo.GetAssembly()
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.GetType(BinaryAssemblyInfo assemblyInfo, String name)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectMap..ctor(String objectName, String[] memberNames, BinaryTypeEnum[] binaryTypeEnumA, Object[] typeInformationA, Int32[] memberAssemIds, ObjectReader objectReader, Int32 objectId, BinaryAssemblyInfo assemblyInfo, SizedArray assemIdToAssemblyTable)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.__BinaryParser.ReadObjectWithMapTyped(BinaryObjectWithMapTyped record)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.__BinaryParser.ReadObjectWithMapTyped(BinaryHeaderEnum binaryHeaderEnum)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.__BinaryParser.Run()
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.Deserialize(HeaderHandler handler, __BinaryParser serParser, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize(Stream serializationStream, HeaderHandler handler, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize(Stream serializationStream)
```

Has anyone had a similar issue and solved it?

The only way forward that I can see, is either sticking the assembly in the GAC and pray that it can find it, or reduce my object to a string.

*File: myeventhandler.cs*

```
namespace MyAssembly
{
    [TcmExtension("This does stuff")]
    public sealed class MyEventHandler : TcmExtension
    {

        public MyEventHandler()
        {
            EventSystem.Subscribe<PublishTransaction, SaveEventArgs>(
                (subject, args, phase) =>

                    // pseudo code!
                    foreach (var item in PublishTransaction))
                    {
                        var appData = item.ReadApplicationData(MyAppDataId);
                        if(appData != null)
                        {
                            var myAppData = appData.GetAs<MyClass>();
                            // do stuff with myAppData
                        }
                    }
                },
                EventPhases.TransactionCommited
            );
        }
    }
}
```

*File: myclass.cs*

```
namespace MyAssembly
{
    [Serializable]
    public class MyClass
    {
        // has properties and constructors
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you have the wrong version of the Assembly deployed? I have used different classes in Event Systems (from the same assembly and from dependencies) and never had issues there.

Comment: Can you please elaborate what actually you are trying to do:
means Have you written a particular Event Handler for a Tridion activity and there you have written the above said code and you are getting the above error when this event is triggered...kindly elaborate if my assumptions are wrong

Comment: Nuno, I only have one version deployed and it's only reference is the `<add assemblyFile>` entry in the Tridion.ContentManager.config file. I know it's the correct version of the assembly as additional debug logging added to the event handler shows up correctly.

Comment: Have you tried restarting COM+ Application?

Comment: Only about 15 times today :) can't deploy a new version of the DLL without shutting down COM+

Comment: In that case can you double sure your assembly info...you may check the AssemblyInfo.cs file or better I would say try explore it through ILDASM tool for your dll available at the path specified in the Tridion Manager Config file and ensure the Fully Qualified name in config is same as shown by the ILDASM.

From my experience I would say you may face even more problem if you try to use GAC as compared to this recommended approach.

Comment: Could it be that the AppData was set/saved with/as a different version of the MyAssembly.MyClass? If so, could you try to set the AppData again with the same version as you are using in your eventhandler?

Answer (score 6):

Can't say I know anything specific about this version of Tridion, but if I was getting odd loader errors, I'd fire up the Fusion Log Viewer. Scott Hanselman describes it [here.](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BackToBasicsUsingFusionLogViewerToDebugObscureLoaderErrors.aspx)

That can help you work out where .Net has been looking - which might give you a clue as to what's up.